# WPF/VB ComboBox SelectionChanged Fires Twice

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I am new to WPF.  The project I am working on has requirements to use VB as language and flat files as data (I can not change requirements).  I only found (2) books on WPF with VB compared to the dozens in C and web searches are as scarce. Hoping someone out there has some insight on this issue with VB experience.

This is a cascading event on the page. I load a combobox called unit. When a selection is made in unit, it makes the facility combobox available and loads with data based on the unit value selected. If unit changes again, it clears the facility box and reload based on new unit value.

My code is below. What truly confuses me is the results of the load of the facility combobox.  It is loaded as if the reading of the flat file is looped twice.  At the top of the function is code to clear the list before loading the combobox.  So, if even if the function was called twice, the code should technically clear the list, load, clear the list again and then load.  I put in a series of popups to confirm the SelectionChange is called twice and therefor the load facility is called twice.

I looked at the sender and e arguments and they are the same in both calls so I am not sure how to trap and stop the second call or what is even triggering it.

Oh, a really strange thing happened with the popups.  Where they are placed now in the VB code, makes the issue go away.  I only see one occurrence of the facility in the combobox.  If I take away the popups, I get two occurrences again.

Anyone see something I am missing?  Thanks in advance for your review and assistance.

XAML:

```
<Grid  x:Name="gridTreat1" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblTreat1Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Treatment Details     1 of 3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="459" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblUnit" Text="Unit:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" FontSize="18" Height="34" BorderBrush="White" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboUnit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="586" Height="34" FontSize="18" SelectionChanged="cboUnit_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblFacility" Text="Facility:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" FontSize="18" Height="34" BorderBrush="White" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboFacility" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="586" Height="34" FontSize="16" SelectionChanged="cboFacility_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblPhysician" Text="Physician:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" FontSize="18" Height="34" BorderBrush="White" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboPhysician" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="586" Height="34" FontSize="16">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblStep2" Text="------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="754" Height="34" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="White" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
    <Button x:Name="cmdCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,502,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Height="50" FontSize="18" />
    <Button x:Name="cmdNext" Content="NEXT &gt;&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="618,502,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Height="50" FontSize="18"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="recPatient" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="544,18,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblPRN" Text="PRN:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="550,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Height="20" Background="#FFF4F4F5" BorderBrush="#FFF4F4F5" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False" TabIndex="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="lblPatName" Text="Patient:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="550,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="20" Background="#FFF4F4F5" BorderBrush="#FFF4F4F5" FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False" TabIndex="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtPRN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" Margin="625,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Background="#FFF4F4F5" BorderBrush="#FFF4F4F5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False" TabIndex="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtPatName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="625,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Background="#FFF4F4F5" BorderBrush="#FFF4F4F5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False" TabIndex="0"/>
    <TextBox Text="CONFIDENTIAL PEER REVIEW PRIVILEGED" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,558,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="14" IsTabStop="False" TabIndex="0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,399,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTest2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,436,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

VB Code Behind:

```
    Private Sub cboUnit_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cboUnit.SelectionChanged
    Dim myUnit As String = ""
    Dim cb As ComboBox
    Dim cbi As ComboBoxItem
    cb = CType(cboUnit, ComboBox)
    cbi = CType(cb.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem)
    myUnit = cbi.Tag.ToString
    Select Case GlobalVariable.gvAction
        Case "A"
            Call Load_cboFacility(myUnit)
            Me.cboFacility.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
            Me.lblFacility.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
        Case "E"
            Call Load_cboFacility(myUnit,"2")
    End Select
End Sub

Private Async Sub Load_cboFacility(ByVal myUnit As String, Optional myIsSel As String = "")
    Dim nextline As String = ""
    Dim myTag As String = ""
    Dim myKey As String = ""
    Dim myContent As String = ""
    Dim localfolder As Windows.Storage.StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim myfile As StorageFile = Await localfolder.GetFileAsync("dicFacility.txt")

    Dim cb As ComboBox
    Dim cbi As ComboBoxItem
    Dim myMsg2 As New MessageDialog("1")
    Await myMsg2.ShowAsync

    cb = CType(cboFacility, ComboBox)
    cb.Items.Clear()

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Await myfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync)
        Dim myMsg As New MessageDialog("2")
        Await myMsg.ShowAsync
        nextline = Await reader.ReadLineAsync
        While (nextline <> Nothing)
            myKey = nextline.Substring(0, 2)
            myKey = myKey.Trim
            If myUnit = myKey Then
                myTag = nextline.Substring(7, 4)
                myTag = myTag.Trim
                myContent = nextline.Substring(18, nextline.Length - 18)
                cbi = New ComboBoxItem
                cbi.Tag = myTag
                cbi.Content = myContent
                If myIsSel <> "" Then
                    If myIsSel = myTag Then
                        cbi.IsSelected = True
                    End If
                End If
                cb.Items.Add(cbi)
            End If
            nextline = Await reader.ReadLineAsync
        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

**Revision to Question:**

I finally got code working as a variation of what I think Rachel suggested I do. It is not elegant but functions.  If someone has a cleaner way, I am open to suggestions:

Modified XAML by adding a DropDownClosed event:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboUnit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="586" Height="34" FontSize="18" SelectionChanged="cboUnit_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="cboUnit_Closed" />
```

Modified VB Code:

In my constants.vb file, I created a new variable called gvUnitCount and set to zero initially. When drop down closes, my count is reset to zero. When selection changed, it runs once and IF statement kicks you out if increments higher.

```
Private Sub cboUnit_Closed(sender As System.Object, e As Object) Handles cboUnit.DropDownClosed
    GlobalVariable.gvUnitCount = 0
End Sub

Private Sub cboUnit_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cboUnit.SelectionChanged
    Dim myUnit As String = ""
    Dim cbUnit2 As ComboBox
    Dim cbiUnit2 As ComboBoxItem
    cbUnit2 = CType(cboUnit, ComboBox)
    cbiUnit2 = CType(cbUnit2.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem)
    myUnit = cbiUnit2.Tag.ToString
    Me.txtUnitTag.Text = cbiUnit2.Tag.ToString

    If GlobalVariable.gvUnitCount = 0 Then
        Select Case GlobalVariable.gvAction
            Case "A"
                Me.cboFacility.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
                Me.lblFacility.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
                Call Load_cboFacility(myUnit)
                Me.cboPhysician.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
                Me.lblPhysician.Visibility = Xaml.Visibility.Visible
                Call Load_cboPhysician(myUnit)
            Case "E"
                Call Load_cboFacility(myUnit)
                Call Load_cboPhysician(myUnit)
        End Select
        GlobalVariable.gvUnitCount = GlobalVariable.gvUnitCount + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Like I said, not pretty but functions.  I am consistently getting only one load of the facility combobox this way.

Comment: :( Your XAML makes me a sad panda. That said though, my best guess is it is firing twice (once for unselection, once for selection?) and running concurrently on separate threads, so the .Clear is called twice, then the load is called twice, resulting in two copies of each item. I'd suggest adding an `isLoadingFacility` flag that is used to prevent the second call if codes are already being loaded

Comment: Sorry sad panda, I did say I was new, but I like your idea. Will give it a try between flights today. Thx. : )

Comment: I tried flagging and changing event to DropDownClosed instead of SelectionChanged.  My code still creates two occurrences in the Facility Combo Box.  In all cases, Unit changed is called twice after selecting an item and as such calls load_cboFacility twice. It just doesn't make sense to me what is happening.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code you are using to set a bool flag when loading data?

Comment: Edited and above.  This way is working.  All other attempts to streamline have failed. I think this is a variation of what you suggested. Since it is working and you gave me the push, I am thinking of marking as answered by you but understand if code to ugly for your credit : )